# AKS log query not resulting correct results

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to find out the failed pods of just last 1hour in AKS. I have used azure provided sample query:

```
// List all the pods count with phase 
// View pod phase counts based on all phases: Failed, Pending, Unknown, Running, or Succeeded. 
// To create an alert for this query, click '+ New alert rule'
//Customize endDateTime, startDateTime to select different time range
   let endDateTime = now();
    let startDateTime = ago(1h);
    let trendBinSize = 1m;
    KubePodInventory
    | where TimeGenerated < endDateTime
    | where TimeGenerated >= startDateTime
    | distinct ClusterName, TimeGenerated, _ResourceId
    | summarize ClusterSnapshotCount = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, trendBinSize), ClusterName, _ResourceId
    | join hint.strategy=broadcast (
        KubePodInventory
        | where TimeGenerated < endDateTime
        | where TimeGenerated >= startDateTime
        | distinct ClusterName, Computer, PodUid, TimeGenerated, PodStatus, _ResourceId
        | summarize TotalCount = count(), //Calculating count for per pod status
                    PendingCount = sumif(1, PodStatus =~ 'Pending'),
                    RunningCount = sumif(1, PodStatus =~ 'Running'),
                    SucceededCount = sumif(1, PodStatus =~ 'Succeeded'),
                    FailedCount = sumif(1, PodStatus =~ 'Failed')
                 by ClusterName, bin(TimeGenerated, trendBinSize), _ResourceId
    ) on ClusterName, TimeGenerated, _ResourceId
    | extend UnknownCount = TotalCount - PendingCount - RunningCount - SucceededCount - FailedCount
    | project TimeGenerated, _ResourceId,
    TotalCount = todouble(TotalCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount,
              PendingCount = todouble(PendingCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount,
              RunningCount = todouble(RunningCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount,
              SucceededCount = todouble(SucceededCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount,
              FailedCount = todouble(FailedCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount,
              UnknownCount = todouble(UnknownCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount
```

But all the counts returned from the query example FailedCount are not of just last 1 hour, they are the number of total failed pods from the time when cluster was created.

I am not sure what is wrong in the query, if anyone has any suggestions pls reply.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: could you please provide that query you used? and what's your Kubernetes version?

Comment: query used a have mentioned in the question, kuberntes version 1.18.14

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below query and got the results only for 1 Hour.

Query used:

```
   let endDateTime = now();
    let startDateTime = 1h;
    let trendBinSize = 1m;
    KubePodInventory
    | where TimeGenerated >= ago(startDateTime)
    | distinct ClusterName, TimeGenerated, _ResourceId
    | summarize ClusterSnapshotCount = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, trendBinSize), ClusterName, _ResourceId
    | join hint.strategy=broadcast (
        KubePodInventory
    | where TimeGenerated >= ago(startDateTime)
        | distinct ClusterName, Computer, PodUid, TimeGenerated, PodStatus, _ResourceId
        | summarize TotalCount = count(), //Calculating count for per pod status
                    PendingCount = sumif(1, PodStatus =~ 'Pending'),
                    RunningCount = sumif(1, PodStatus =~ 'Running'),
                    SucceededCount = sumif(1, PodStatus =~ 'Succeeded'),
                    FailedCount = sumif(1, PodStatus =~ 'Failed')
                 by ClusterName, bin(TimeGenerated, trendBinSize), _ResourceId
    ) on ClusterName, TimeGenerated, _ResourceId
    | extend UnknownCount = TotalCount - PendingCount - RunningCount - SucceededCount - FailedCount
    | project TimeGenerated, _ResourceId,
    TotalCount = todouble(TotalCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount,
              PendingCount = todouble(PendingCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount,
              RunningCount = todouble(RunningCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount,
              SucceededCount = todouble(SucceededCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount,
              FailedCount = todouble(FailedCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount,
              UnknownCount = todouble(UnknownCount) / ClusterSnapshotCount
```

**Output**
[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-log-query

Comment: i think you misinterpreted the question, i do not want the time duration to be 1 hours like shown in chart. I want that only those pods are counted that failed in last 1 hour. Example if there are two pods of age 8hours and 0.5 hours in failed status, i do not want the count to be 2 for failed pods, i want to have the query that can return the failed pods for age less then 1 hours, so my query should be returning output 1 (ignoring the pod failed 8hours ago)